# Spring boot test profiling

Tags: testing, spring-boot

I have for example 3 developers : DEV1, DEV2 and DEV3. I want every one has their own application-DEV1(2)(3)-properties in /test/resources/ folder.

I have an class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
```

I don't want to use @ActiveProfiles annotation on class because than every time you want to run tests every user has to added value to load their own configurations. 
I am using IntelliJ so I set Maven run configuration with command

```
clean test
```

and profile DEV1 eg.

When I run test result is next: On the start up of test running output I can see:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dspring.profiles.active=DEV1
```

But it comes to concrete test class output is :

```
2015-12-29 12:52:10.129  INFO 17211 --- [           main] MyClassTest  : Starting MyClassTest on dev with PID 17211 
2015-12-29 12:52:10.130  INFO 17211 --- [           main] MyClassTest  : No profiles are active
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is IntelliJ problem or some configuration gap, but what works is

```
clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=DEV1
```

in the Command line parameter of Maven configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To complement your post: [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) of SpringBoot documentation show all alternatives to *externalize* your configuration of profiles.

In priority order:

- Command line arguments.
- Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property)
- JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
- Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
- OS environment variables.
- A RandomValuePropertySource that only has properties in random.*.
- Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
- Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
- Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
- Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
- @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
- Default properties (specified using SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).